# Java - incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Object;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfRounds = -1; 

        while (numberOfRounds <= -1) { 
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please input the number of rounds. The number of rounds must be greater than or equal to 0: ");
            numberOfRounds = reader.hasNextInt();
            reader.close();
        }
        System.out.println("number is" + numberOfRounds);
    }
}
```

I've been trying to get the user to input a number of rounds. But the rounds have to be greater than or equal to 0, because negative numbers do not work. Any help?

Error code below:

```
Game.java:11: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int
                    numberOfRounds = reader.hasNextInt();
                                                      ^
1 error
```

Comment: `reader.hasNextInt()` returns a boolean

Comment: `reader.nextInt()`.

Comment: `hasNextInt()` tells you *whether* there is an int to read. `nextInt` actually retrieves the token.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `reader.hasNextInt();` you should use `reader.nextInt();`

But remember that this method throws 3 types of errors which should be handled:

- `InputMismatchException` - if the next token does not match the
  Integer regular expression, or is out of range
- `NoSuchElementException` - if input is exhausted
- `IllegalStateException` - if this scanner is closed

Comment: potential InputMismatchException tho

Comment: Thank you, this makes the program run, but I am indeed getting both the InputMismatchException and NoSuchElementException. Do you have advice for how to handle these?

Comment: You can handle it using standard try-catch block